# Error 98:Conflict with previous definition of x for attribute 'type'

Tags: c, struct, 8051, sdcc

I am getting this compile error using SDCC and programming an old 8051.
I am trying to make 1wire search command work. I got my hands on an OneWire library that I started modifying for my hardware/software and now I am stuck behind this error:

```
C:\sdcc\code>sdcc test3.c
test3.c:164: error 98: conflict with previous definition of 'OW_search' for  attribute 'type'
from type 'int function ( struct OW_info generic* fixed, unsigned-char fixed) fixed'
to type 'int function ( struct OW_info generic* fixed, unsigned-char fixed) fixed'
```

The lines where the error come in are the following.

```
183:...
184:int OW_search(struct OW_info *info)
185:{
186:unsigned char *buffer;
187:int id_bit_number;
188 ...
```

Just in case, the declaration of OW_info

```
struct OW_info
{
unsigned char family;
unsigned char serialNum[6];
unsigned char crc;

};
```

I am prototyping the function above

```
int OW_search(struct OW_info *info);
```

I can not find a proper reason why I am getting that compile error. I am hoping for some hints why it would come there. Thanks.

And a link to download my entire code http://www.upload.ee/files/4489287/test3.txt.html

Comment: where exactly your `struct OW_info` definition present? somewhere at line 5?

Comment: More like 101, it is not inside the main.

Comment: right. i'm much worried about the `'OW` part in the print `previous definition of  'OW`. Can you please make sure there's no typo?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm sorry, i cut out a bit of the error. It's fully there now.

Comment: You must have some other prototype as `int OW_search(struct OW_info *info, char p);` or similar. Maybe check all the header files?

Comment: I checked all the header files, that could have had this declaration, i did not find any, i even excluded them, just in case. I did that all yesterday.

Comment: I upload my entire code, if you think that would help.

Comment: Is is too big? If possible, please upload, maybe some other pair of eyes will be able to track down the issue, if any. :-)

Comment: Here is the code http://www.upload.ee/files/4489287/test3.txt.html

Comment: My wild stab-in-the dark suggestion would be to move the definition of `struct OW_info` from after the prototype to before it... maybe the compiler (probably incorrectly) sees "pointer-to-not-yet-defined structure" as different to "pointer-to-defined-structure"?

Comment: Excuse my language, but... i can't f*king believe this **** worked.
This is unheard of... I have tens of prototypes that use variables declared after.
Does struct work in another way when declaring?

Comment: You could just try putting `struct OW_info;` ahead of the prototype declaration (in a sense, prototyping the structure).  Without either of these, Microsoft's C compiler (VS2008) with `/Wall` produces a warning ("_warning C4115: 'OW_info' : named type definition in parentheses_") so maybe you _should_ "declare" the structure before using it in a prototype (I am not a C language lawyer enough to know), but _most_ compilers don't mind.  My limited experience (from 20 years ago) with 8051 and similar compilers is that they often have "quirks" like this!

Comment: You already got your up vote with your previous comment. If i did not make my joy clear enough...Thank you very much man, that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the errors because I declared the structures after prototyping my functions.
Thanks to @TripeHound it is now know that structures have to be declared before prototyping a function and after further research it seems that there is no other way.

Comment: You probably meant defined, not declared. And you can go around it by just `typedef`-ing the structure declaration, putting the typedef before the function and using it in the prototype, like this:

    `typedef struct OW_info OW_info; /* ... */ int OW_search(OW_info *info); /* ...and after that come the struct definition and then the function body... */`

Should work.

Comment: Note: this all happens because the compiler treats the `struct` in the function prototype and the actual `struct` as two different structs, because they belong to different scopes. That's completely standartized behaviour.

Comment: Yea, as someone who has never used structs before yesterday, it was a real mind breaker, since i did not know i have to define(?) the structure before. Thanks for making it even more clear.

Comment: this might help you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration =)